# Silverlight Windows look and feel

Tags: silverlight, look-and-feel

I'm looking at using Silverlight to create a multi-file uploader for one of our internal apps that we're working on. The only Silverlight UI that I need is a choose button so that I can initiate an OpenFileDialog instance. Is there a way to easily make a button in Silverlight look like the operating system standard buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some themes that are in the Silverlight Toolkit: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%203&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=silverlight

But those don't change based on the operating system of the user. 
For example you would set the Vista look for your app, but your user is using a Mac.

Comment: You say that they change based on the OS of the user--so you mean Windows will look like Windows and Mac will look like Mac? If so, that sounds like it might be what I'm after--more native-looking controls. I'm not sure, though, based on your link, that this is what you mean--I don't see anything that looks like native controls :-)

Comment: Well no, I mean to say, that it will not look native at all. I had a typo in my response.

Comment: I think you are stuck with the default style or your own, there is no other way to display native style buttons: http://forums.silverlight.net/t/1546.aspx/1